# How to wait for the number of list items to change in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a list and I want to test filtering (you input some text, and the list gets filtered).

So, in Cypress, I'd like to wait some time for that number of items to change. I don't know the number of items that I should expect. It would also be great if I wouldn't care whether that number is greater or lesser than the initial number.

How should I go with this? I tried `cy.wait(1000)` but it did nothing (I guess because the list items are already there, so it didn't wait at all)...

**EDIT1**:

I'm trying to get the initial number of items from this code, but `itemsCountBefore` gets set to `7` inside the lambda function, but when it gets outside (second log) it is `undefined`

```
  let itemsCountBefore;
  cy.get(homePage.elements.anyListItem).then(($listItems) => {
    itemsCountBefore = $listItems.length;
    cy.log(`itemsCountBefore1: ${itemsCountBefore}`)
  });
  cy.log(`itemsCountBefore2: ${itemsCountBefore}`)
```

Comment: do you know initial number of items in the list? before typing the text

Comment: Yes, I can get that

Comment: Is there a request made after submitting the text filtering?

Comment: @jjhelguero no. It just filters the already fetched data.

Comment: Is there any indication on the UI that shows the loading of the filtered data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you need to wait for the external count variable to be updated before checking it's value.

To do so use a `.then()` callback after the action that makes the change (the filtering action).

Also is useful to use a `.should()` to make your assertion. If the action involves some asynchronous activity (like sending the filter input to a server), you need some retry happening to avoid flaky test results.

The simplest assertion is that `current` does not equal `initial`.

```js
let initial;

cy.get(homePage.elements.anyListItem)
  .its('length')
  .then(count => initial = count)

cy.get('input-filter-selector')
  .type('filter-text')
  .then(() => {
    cy.get(homePage.elements.anyListItem)
      .its('length')
      .should('not.eq', initial)
  })
```

Comment: Damn! This worked! Thanks!
But do you know why my previous attempt didn't (those lines of code in **EDIT1** section of my question)? Why did my variable lose the value and became `undefined` when it left the `then` block?

Comment: It's loading the command `cy.log(itemsCountBefore2: ${itemsCountBefore})` on to the queue before it starts running the queue, so the value of `itemsCountBefore` is still `undefined` at that time - chicken and egg problem. When you use a `.then()` with callback, the commands inside the callback aren't loaded until previous commands have run. It's a really confusing result of the way that Cypress queue system works.

Comment: Aha! That sounds reasonable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

1-Get the initial number of items in the list.

2-Perform the action that triggers the filtering.

3-Use cy.wait() to wait for the number of items to change.

```
let initialItemCount;
cy.get('list-selector').then(($list) => {
  initialItemCount = $list.children().length;
});

cy.get('input-filter-selector').type('filter-text');

cy.waitUntil(() => {
  cy.get('list-selector').then(($list) => {
    const currentItemCount = $list.children().length;
    // Wait until the number of items changes from the initial count
    return currentItemCount !== initialItemCount;
  });
}, { timeout: 5000, interval: 500 });
```

Comment: Looks like this answer depends on the `cypress-wait-until` package. You may want to include that in the answer as well.

Comment: yes, exactly. you need to import cypress-wait-until package

Comment: I'm trying this now, but I'm getting `undefined` as the value of `itemsCountBefore` in this code:
```
        let itemsCountBefore;
        cy.get(homePage.elements.anyListItem).then(($listItems) => {
            itemsCountBefore = $listItems.length;
        });
```
The difference from your solution is that I'm selecting the list items, instead of the list itself, but I guess it's the same as yours `$list.children()`

Comment: And in the test log it says that first it matched 7 elements, and then, after filtering, it matched 3 elements

Comment: I checked it now - inside that first `then` variable `itemsCountBefore` is set to 7. But immediately after, when it leaves lambda function, it's set to `undefined`

Comment: can you try adding global variable and save the value of itemsCountBefore inside the lambda function, then try to access or use that value outside the function.